# SignalR hubclass in classlibrary

Tags: c#, javascript, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a signalr hubclass in a classlibrary

and when i use that hubclass in my webapplication referencing that class library with below javascript code, it does not work,

```
$(function () {

    var chat = $.connection.notificationHub;

    chat.client.newMessage = function (message) {
        alert(message);

        $('#messages').append('<li><strong>' +  message + '</strong>: </li>');
    };
    $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

Comment: it's not really clear from your question what doesn't work; you should add the server-side code and explain what you expected to happen

Answer (score 2):

You need an event to trigger your method in Hub class. See below example:

**NotificationHub in the class library**

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.newMessage(message);
    }
}
```

**Web application**

```
<input type="text" id="message" />
<input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
<ul id="messages"></ul>

   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            var chat = $.connection.notificationHub;
            chat.client.newMessage = function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                $('#messages').append('<li><strong>' + data + '</strong>: </li>');
            };
            $('#message').focus();
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                console.log("Connected");
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    chat.server.send($('#message').val());
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Note**

Because you the hubclass is in the class library, you need to install `Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR` package in it. You also need to install it in the webapplication. Then add hubclass reference to webapplication. Add `app.MapSignalR()` in your Startup class, like below:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have the same issue I don't get your point  ConfigureAuth(app);
?? and why declare it as partial??

Comment: Startup class will be in class library or web application?

Comment: @bilal, Startup class is where you specify components for the application pipeline, therefor it should be in the web application.