# SIgnal R hub class not defined..Error loading Hubs

Tags: signalr

I am developing a real time application based on signal R . I am using .NET framework 4 , Signal R version 1.2.2 in VS 2010.I am getting a Hub reference error stating

```
Uncaught Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/hubs'></script>.
```

I got a solution to add the Hub reference in  global file. But since i am using  DNN framework it contains multiple projects and have a common global file.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs("/myhubs", new HubConfiguration());
```

i tried adding this piece of code there, but it too didn't works..

my hub class

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{

    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Clients.Others.receive(message);
    }

}
```

And start up class is

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(DotNetNuke.Modules.VideoChat.Startup))]

namespace DotNetNuke.Modules.VideoChat
{
public class Startup 
  {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      app.MapHubs();
    }
  }
}
```

i am using jquery on client side.

```
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {}
```

Can anyone suggest a way around

Comment: Please add you Hub Code

Comment: Edited the code..pls check @Shachaf.Gortler

Comment: @Ranjith J : see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow these steps:

1. Create a Hub class on the server that inherits the `Hub` class from SignalR
2. Create client proxy for the Hub class (using .NET class or javascript code)
3. Startup the Hub on the server using MapHubs() (obsolete)

Your question does not give enought information. Is it a web application? Are you using javascript or .NET on the client side?

See this post: [SignalR hubclass in classlibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795982/signalr-hubclass-in-classlibrary)

**EDIT**

Here is what you should have in your Startup class now that I see that you are using OWIN:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup("StartupConfiguration", typeof(DotNetNuke.Modules.VideoChat.Startup))]
namespace DotNetNuke.Modules.VideoChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // SignalR Hub Startup
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
            hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            hubConfiguration.EnableJavaScriptProxies = true;
            hubConfiguration.EnableJSONP = false;

            app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);


        }
    }
}
```

In your web.config, add these lines:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="StartupConfiguration" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup " value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: Edited my question...  @Beaulieu